# Paypal API credentials, security concern

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing a WP plugin that will allow Paypal payments and invoicing. This plugin will allow users to use their **own** Paypal accounts when accepting payments.

What I understand so far is I need to use REST to enable the Invoicing API. So it leaves me with two options:

1. Let the users create their own app and enter the client id and secret key into the plugin settings.
2. Use my own app that I created (only for this purpose) and go with Third Party Payment instead: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreateThirdPartyPayment.html

My concern for the first one is that by saving the keys in the database and their site gets compromised somehow - the hackers can execute the API on behalf of their app.

The second one will show the secret keys on the plugin file itself - but then again since the app will only used for this purpose and the Payee/Merchant will only be specified in the plugin settings I guess this is okay? Another advantage would be the user not needing to create their own app.

Which one is better of the two or maybe you can recommend a third option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always generate dynamic payment buttons (similar to what the wizard in paypal does) based on the parameters your user inputs in your plugin and use the express checkout endpoint.But you'll lose some features (like complete customization of the checkout process)

Comment: Thanks but I needed to have invoicing as well and that could only be achieved with the REST API. I went with option 2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Store the API keys in your database but salt and hash them because they are passwords. Since you are using a third-party CMS, you should assume that sooner or later it is going to have a zero-day exploit and, sooner or later, you will have a hacker with root access to your CMS admin. Design your database and plugins with this fact in mind.